# Getting different results using the pipeline with functions

Tags: function, powershell, pipeline

I'm finding that passing objects to functions through the PowerShell pipeline converts them to `string` objects.  If I pass the object as a parameter it keeps its type.  To demonstrate:

I have the following PowerShell function which displays a object's type and value:

```
function TestFunction {
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )] $InputObject
    )

    Echo $InputObject.GetType().Name
    Echo $InputObject
}
```

I ran this script to test the function:

```
[string[]] $Array = "Value 1", "Value 2"

# Result outside of function.
Echo $Array.GetType().Name
Echo $Array
Echo ""

# Calling function with parameter.
TestFunction $Array
Echo ""

# Calling function with pipeline.
$Array | TestFunction
```

This produces the output:

```
String[]
Value 1
Value 2

String[]
Value 1
Value 2

String
Value 2
```

EDIT: How can I use the pipeline to pass an entire array to a function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To process multiple items recieved via the pipeline you need a process block in your function:

```
function Test-Function {
    param (
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $Test
    )

    process {
        $Test.GetType().FullName
        $Test
    }
}

[string[]] $Array = "Value 1", "Value 2"
$Array | Test-Function
```

More info:

- `get-help about_functions` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347712.aspx
- `get-help about_Functions_Advanced` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315326.aspx

Comment: Beautiful!  That's got it working.  Thanks!  And next time, I'll RTFM.  :-)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to having a process block you also need to process each item in the array. It is needed when the array is passed as an argument, not via piping. Consider this:

```
function Test-Function 
{
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )] $InputObject
    )

    process
    {
        $InputObject.GetType().Name
    }
}

$Array = "Value 1","Value 2"
Test-Function $array
```

The result would be String[], which is probably not what you want. The following command will print the type of each item in the array no matter how the argument is passed:

```
function Test-Function 
{
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )] $InputObject
    )

    process
    {
        foreach($i in $InputObject)
        {
            $i.GetType().Name
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about an array of hashtables?  I already have a Process block and the array is still unrolled on the pipeline.

Nevermind, I figured it out.   In this example it would be `Test-Function ,$array`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing something that is not a string into that function?

Try out: 
`1, 2 | TestFunction`

EDIT:

Try this.  The only change I made was to add a *process* block around $InputObject

```
function TestFunction {
    param (
        [Parameter(
            Position=0,
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true
        )] $InputObject
    )

    process
    {
    Echo $InputObject.GetType().Name
    Echo $InputObject
    }
}
```

Comment: That shows as `Int32[]` for the first two tests, and `Int32` for the final test.  The final test still only displays the last value instead of the whole array.  I've edited the question to clarify.